# How to select clicked element from search result and remove the siblings in angular4

Tags: angular, jquery-ui, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

I am getting array of element as search result from searchbox, on click i want to get clicked element in my search box and remove the remaining sibling li. Not sure how can i achieve it using angular.

[image]

Thanks for your time and help.

```
<div id="search-component">
        <input type="text" class="searchBox"
            placeholder="Search here..." #searchBox id="searchBox"
            name="searchBox" (keyup)="searchproducts(searchBox.value)" />
            <ul id= "SearchTest" class="search-result" *ngFor="let product of products?.searchData| slice:0:4">
           <li (click)="getproducts(product.id);searchBox.value = product.name;">{{product.name}}</li></ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `product.id` and `product.name` since in ngFor you have used product as variable.

```
<li (click)="getproducts(product.id);searchBox.value = product.name;">{{product.name}}</li></ul>
```

Also, to hide all the links, you can select `SearchTest` id and apply `display:none;` to it. And whenever input field is edited, you can make the SearchTest id  `display:block;`

Edit 1:

```
getproducts(id){
    document.getElementById('SearchTest').style.display = "none";
    // your code here
}

searchproducts(value){
   document.getElementById('SearchTest').style.display = "block";
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: sorry, as i am new so not sure how can we do that, it will be great if you can tell me where i should put display none and when to put display:block for li in order to hide the remaining li;

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope this should help you.

Comment: In angular4 can we write like this. As i have separate getproducts and searchproducts in my component.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. There are multiple ways of achieving what you want. This method achieves without much processing in ts file. Rather just plays on the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Template
Use ngModel to show selected product name.

```
<div id="search-component">
        <input [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" type="text" class="searchBox"
            placeholder="Search here..." #searchBox id="searchBox"
            name="searchBox" (keyup)="searchproducts(searchBox.value)" />
            <ul id= "SearchTest" class="search-result" *ngFor="let product of products?.searchData| slice:0:4">
           <li (click)="getproducts(products.id);searchBox.value = products.name;">{{products.name}}</li></ul>
    </div>
```

Class
Empty the array to hide all suggestions.

```
getproducts(products.id) {
 this.selecteItem = products.name;
 this.products = [];
}
```